# jQuery code for show() and hide() works in console, but doesn't work in code base; error thrown says ".show() and .hide() not a function"

Tags: jquery

I added a new div containing a headline which I want to first hide and then show and hide upon mouseenter and mouseleave.  This code works fine in the console, but it doesn't work when I execute it in the code base.

```
var optly = function() {
$('.nh-copy-wrap > .title').each(function() {
if ($(this).html().indexOf('Market to a person, not a segment')>-1 && $(this).hasClass('optly') == false) {
  $("<div class= \"promo-h2\">Personalization solutions help you tailor messages to match customers across devices and channels...</div>").insertAfter(this);
  $("div.nh-promo-card-holder:contains('Market to a person, not a segment')").find("div.nh-icon.ibm-arrow-forward-link").addClass("personalization-cta");
  $(".nh-icon.ibm-marketplace-link").addClass("marketplace-logo");
  $(this).addClass('optly');
}
else if ($(this).html().indexOf('Understand and engage in the mobile moment')>-1 && $(this).hasClass('optly') == false) {
  $("<div class= \"promo-h2\">Six billion mobile devices is a big target for marketers. Mobile marketing solutions allow marketers to engage customers...</div>").insertAfter(this);
  $("div.nh-promo-card-holder:contains('Understand and engage in the mobile moment')").find("div.nh-icon.ibm-arrow-forward-link").addClass("mobile-cta");
  $(".nh-icon.ibm-marketplace-link").addClass("marketplace-logo");
  $(this).addClass('optly');
}
else if ($(this).html().indexOf('Create high performing, highly-relevant emails')>-1 && $(this).hasClass('optly') == false) {
  $("<div class= \"promo-h2\">Six billion mobile devices is a big target for marketers. Mobile marketing solutions allow marketers to engage customers through these pervasive devices with...</div>").insertAfter(this);
  $("div.nh-promo-card-holder:contains('Create high performing, highly-relevant emails')").find("div.nh-icon.ibm-arrow-forward-link").addClass("email-cta");
  $(".nh-icon.ibm-marketplace-link").addClass("marketplace-logo");
  $(this).addClass('optly');
}
});
setInterval(optly, 50);
};

var HoverOver = function() {
$(".nh-promo-card-holder").bind("mouseenter", function() {$(".promo-    h2").show();});
$(".nh-promo-card-holder").bind("mouseleave", function() {$(".promo-h2").hide();});
};

$(document).ready(function() {
optly();
setInterval(HoverOver, 200);
});
```

I tried using `$(document).ready` and waiting until the new div is available for manipulation before executing the code below, but the console is still throwing an error that says `"...show() is not a function"` and similarly for hide as well.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Without the full code I could gess that you're either not including jQuery or you're calling `show()` or `hide()` before jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Are you sure this code is being executed after .promo-h2 is added to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Try to place you code into

`$(document).ready(function(){`

`})`

and include jQuery before you script

Comment: Thanks Alex for the quick reply! I tried doing that, but I'm still running into the same error.  I edited the original post with the full code; hope that's enough context!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something else in page is also using `$`

Try wrapping the code in:

```
(function($){
  /* your code */

})(jQuery);
```

Also make sure this loads after jQuery.js loads

Note you should also clear the interval when you do find the element

Answer (score 0):

This most likely happen because the jQuery hasn't been loaded yet. Your code which uses jQuery don't have access to jQuery. The result is that it isn't working.
To solve this you have to do as Alex Muravyov said:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

and move your script element after the jQuery script element.